# Prove inequality on expectation

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities

Random variable $X\geq 0$ and its variance exists. How to prove

$$\mathbb{P}(X\geq(1-t)\mathbb{E}(X))\geq \frac{t^2\mathbb{E}(X)^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}\enspace\text{for}\enspace t\in(0,1]$$

$$\mathbb{E}(\exp(-\lambda(X-\mathbb{E}(X))))\geq\exp(\lambda^2\mathbb{E}(X^2)/2)\enspace\text{for}\enspace \lambda\geq0$$

$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq(1-t)\mathbb{E}(X))\leq \exp(-\frac{t^2\mathbb{E}(X)^2}{2\mathbb{E}(X^2)})\enspace\text{for}\enspace t\in(0,1]$$

Thanks!

---

Update: Thanks to [Alapan Das](https://mathoverflow.net/users/156029/alapan-das) and [Iosif Pinelis](https://mathoverflow.net/users/36721/iosif-pinelis) I found that the first inequality is Paley-Zygumund Inequality. It can be transformed to the shape similar to the third equation i.e.
$$\mathbb{P}(X\leq(1-t)\mathbb{E}(X))\leq 1-\frac{t^2\mathbb{E}(X)^2}{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}\enspace\text{for}\enspace t\in(0,1]$$
but the third one is a tighter bound. I wonder how to improve it.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality

Comment: As one is true, the third inequality doesn't seem to be true in general. Because, $e^{-\frac{\phi^2}{2}}=\phi^2$ for $\phi≈0.83873..$. But, in general $\frac{t\mathbb{E}(X)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X^2)}}$ can be greater than that, but less than $1$ ($t<1$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Alapan Das noted, the first inequality for $t\in[0,1]$ is the [Paley–Zygmund inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paley%E2%80%93Zygmund_inequality). For $t<0$ or $t>1$, the first inequality is false if e.g. $X=1$.

The second inequality is false for all real $\lambda\ne0$ if e.g. $X=1$.

The third inequality is false for all real $t>0$ if e.g. $X=1$. It is also false for all real $t\le-2$  if e.g. $P(X=1)=\frac1{1-t}=1-P(X=0)$.

---

The OP has changed the 3rd inequality from

$$P(X\ge(1-t)EX)\ge\exp-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{2EX^2}$$
for an unspecified $t$ to
$$p_3:=P(X\le(1-t)EX)
\le\exp-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{2EX^2}\tag{3a}\label{3a}$$
for $t\in(0,1]$,
at the same time asserting that the upper bound in \eqref{3a} on $p_3$ is "tighter" than the Paley–Zygmund bound
$$1-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{EX^2}$$
on $p_3$. In fact, it is vice versa:
$$1-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{EX^2}<\exp-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{EX^2}
<\exp-\frac{t^2\,(EX)^2}{2EX^2}$$
(if $EX^2\ne0$).

Comment: Sorry I have edited the condition of $\lambda$ and $t$. I apologize for failing to type them in my original question.

Comment: I apologize for my behavior. I swear that I won't do like it again. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Could you solve/disprove the modified second inequality? I gave it it a shot but wasn't able and now it is bugging me, $\mathbb{E}(\exp(-\lambda(X-\mathbb{E}(X))))\geq 1$ by Jensen's inequality and $\exp(-\lambda^2\mathbb{E}(X^2)/2)\leq 1$ so together they give $\mathbb{E}(\exp(-\lambda(X-\mathbb{E}(X))))\geq\exp(-\lambda^2\mathbb{E}(X^2)/2)$ but that is so far I got. Thanks

Comment: @Dabed : I don't know what you mean by "the modified second inequality". You may want to (carefully state it and) post it separately.

Comment: Thanks, I referred to it as modified since it isn't exactly as first appeared because OP edited it later after you posted your answer, while I would like to know if it true or not I don't know from what source was it extracted or under what circumstances hypothesized so I don't think can really post it separately but don't worry I was asking just in case, I will give it some more thought and if I don't get anywhere soon will just leave it.

Comment: @Dabed : My answer addresses the second posted inequality for all real values of $\lambda$ (for $\lambda=0$ the inequality trivially holds).

Comment: Oh I'm very sorry I didn't read carefully I thought he had modified both equations to make your points invalid so I didn't really check although just setting X=1 was enough to prove it false, zero reading comprehension what I fool I am, sorry again.